Sleeping Ubuntu with a bash script based on docker network traffic
Context

I have a personal homeserver running Ubuntu. I would like it to sleep after the server activity has slowed down to help reduce its power consumption.
I wrote a shell script to check docker bridge network usage. If its below a certain MB threshold I deem the server inactive and suspend it.
I have this script run every 2 hours with cron (for now I'm making it run every 2 minutes for debugging)
I'm running into issues getting this to work properly.

What I've done

First I ssh into my home server
Then I wrote the code for the bash script:

#!/bin/bash

# Usage threshold in bytes (2MB = 5 * 1024 * 1024)
THRESHOLD=$((2 * 1024 * 1024))
INTERVAL=5

calculate_docker_traffic() {
    RX_BEFORE=0
    TX_BEFORE=0

    for IFACE in $(ls /sys/class/net | grep '^br-'); do
        RX_BEFORE=$((RX_BEFORE + $(cat /sys/class/net/$IFACE/statistics/rx_bytes)))
        TX_BEFORE=$((TX_BEFORE + $(cat /sys/class/net/$IFACE/statistics/tx_bytes)))
    done

    echo "$RX_BEFORE $TX_BEFORE"
}

read RX_BEFORE TX_BEFORE < <(calculate_docker_traffic)
sleep $INTERVAL
read RX_AFTER TX_AFTER < <(calculate_docker_traffic)
RX_DIFF=$((RX_AFTER - RX_BEFORE))
TX_DIFF=$((TX_AFTER - TX_BEFORE))
TOTAL_USAGE=$((RX_DIFF + TX_DIFF))

echo $TOTAL_USAGE
if (( TOTAL_USAGE < THRESHOLD )); then
    echo "Docker network usage is below threshold. Suspending system."
    sudo /usr/bin/systemctl suspend
else
    echo "Docker network usage is above threshold. Staying awake."
fi


Then I added it as a cronjob with sudo crontab -e. For debugging I made it run every 2 minutes. I also adding the logger part at the end so I could see the logs of it:

*/2 * * * * /bin/bash /home/drew/auto_sleep.sh | logger -t mycmd


I can grep the logs and see that its running okay with

grep 'mycmd' /var/log/syslog

With the output:
2024-12-30T20:28:01.466156+00:00 yepyolab CRON[2584227]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash /home/drew/auto_sleep.sh | logger -t mycmd)
2024-12-30T20:28:06.479349+00:00 yepyolab mycmd: 7927
2024-12-30T20:28:06.479463+00:00 yepyolab mycmd: Docker network usage is below threshold. Suspending system.


But the issue is the server never suspends

Things I've tried:

added my script to sudo crontab -e instead of crontab -e
updated suspend to not require a password by doing sudo visudo and then drew ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl suspend
used the full path of /usr/bin/systemctl suspend
added a --force to /usr/bin/systemctl suspend --force
Tried manually hard coding the password with $echo <password> | sudo -S systemctl suspend
Tried using sudo pm-suspend

Questions:

Is it not suspending because I'm doing this over ssh?
Is it because systemctl suspend requires a password?
Is there an easier way or another tool to achieve the goal I am after?


"I can grep the logs and see that its running okay with" Can you be more specific? What log lines do you see? In particular, do you see the Docker network usage is below threshold. Suspending system. line?

@NickODell Good call, I will update the post to show the explicit output. But yes I see the echo being logged there but no suspend occurs

What kind of machine is it that you're concerned about power? I'd say don't bother with this scripting, and get yourself an N100 mini or an RPi and the run cost becomes pretty irrelevant.

@AlexHowansky Its a custom PC I built using left over gaming PC parts. Its mainly used for Jellyfin/Media server stuff but I use it for other things. I also happen to live in a city where the power cost is the most expensive in the USA so ideally I would shut it off if I'm not using it. You are right tho a pi would be much more power efficient but I put old parts to use instead of buying a new pi

Script:
I would probably add logs to the code to debug and to verify everything.
Maybe considering adding:
set -x

You could dryrun suspend and check if something is blocking suspend
sudo /usr/bin/systemctl suspend --dry-run

Work your way from there
Questions:

Is it not suspending because I'm doing this over ssh?

Not really sure about that please read this before implementing.
But you can edit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
IdleAction=suspend
IdleActionSec=10min


Is it because systemctl suspend requires a password?

Since you already configured user drew to not need a password this souldnt be the problem.

Is there an easier way or another tool to achieve the goal I am after?

autosuspend (Note: Its also open source)
If anything is unclear, misleading or if you have further questions please let me know :)

Hey thanks for taking time to help me!!! I did a dry run and didn't receive any errors. I'm able to see the logs and that the echo is occurring the way I would expect (I updated the original post to show the logs of the cronjob). I did a simple  /usr/bin/systemctl suspend and its still asking for a password even after editing visudo

doing sudo /usr/bin/systemctl suspend ran the command without asking for password or erroring but the issue is I still stay connected via ssh and the server never sleeps...
Additionally doing sudo pm-suspend again the ssh stays connected and the server does not go to sleep
